# Divide algorithm in two parts without incrementation of version

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=6\baselineskip]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algcompatible}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{My algo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE instruction 1
\STATE instruction 2
\algstore{testcont} 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{My algo - Part 2}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\algrestore{testcont} 
\STATE instruction 3
\STATE instruction 4
\end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

It diplay:

```
Algorithm1 My algo and Algorithm2 My algo - Part 2
```

Please, i ask how can i have:

```
 Algorithm1 My algo and Algorithm1 My algo - Part 2
```

without incrementation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{My algo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE instruction 1
\STATE instruction 2
\algstore{testcont} 
\end{algorithmic}
\addtocounter{algorithm}{-1}%% <===
\end{algorithm}
```

for the first algorithm

Answer (score 3):

With `\ContinuedFloat` from the `caption` package you get also continuing line numbering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE instruction 1
\STATE instruction 2
\algstore{testcont}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{My algo - Part 2}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\algrestore{testcont}
\STATE instruction 3
\STATE instruction 4
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]