# how can divide algorithm on two parts?

Tags: algorithms

Please how can divide my algorithm ? This doesn't work for me. Thanks

```
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{Retrait des ressources } \label{algo:1}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]

 \Debut \strut
 \LState 
 \If {(scoreGA > scoreGB)}

\LState \textbf{A} continue l'exécution 

\algstore{testcont}
\end{algorithmic}
\addtocounter{algorithm}{-1}%% <===
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Retrait des ressources - Partie 2} 
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\algrestore{testcont}

\Else
\LState  B est autorisé. 

\EndIf
\Fin
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you visit these link, please? [1 link] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117613/divide-algorithm-in-two-parts-without-incrementation-of-version) or [2 link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209381/algorithm-split-in-two-parts-need-to-be-consecutive-forcing-the-text-bellow)

Comment: Thank you for help. it didn't work for me because i use \LState and not \STATE

Comment: See this peraphs is the better than the first comment. [Link3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86561/divide-algorithm-inside-if-endif). Hi.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help :) it works for me using Link 3. Another question please: how can i reduce the space between lines in this case ?

Comment: I need a command like: \renewcommand\algorithm[1][]{\Algorithm[#1]\setstretch{0.4}}    ?

Comment: \baselineskip=5pt
  \lineskip=1pt   resolved

Comment: Ok!:-). The important thing is that you've solved it. Good job.

Comment: I have voted +1 for your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the commnts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide algorithm inside If EndIf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86561/divide-algorithm-inside-if-endif)